# How to determine the type of Group from an ldap path

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I determine what the type of group a group would be based on either the group name or the LDAP path.

For example, I am using the following code, and I would like to determine the type of group that I am getting back before I return a response as positive.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // To see if a user has access to a group or resource...
        String userName = Environment.UserName;
        string domainLDAP = GetCurrentDomainLDAP();

        Console.WriteLine(IsUserInMembership(userName, domainLDAP, "_Resource_Test_Group").ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    public static bool IsUserInMembership(string userName, string domainLDAP, string resourceGroupName)
    {
        DirectoryEntry domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry();

        domainConnection.Path = domainLDAP;
        domainConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;


        DirectorySearcher samSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();

        samSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;
        samSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" + userName + ")";
        samSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

        SearchResult samResult = samSearcher.FindOne();

        if (samResult != null)
        {
            DirectoryEntry theUser = samResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
            theUser.RefreshCache(new string[] { "tokenGroups" });

            foreach (byte[] resultBytes in theUser.Properties["tokenGroups"])
            {
                System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier mySID = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(resultBytes, 0);

                DirectorySearcher sidSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();

                sidSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;
                sidSearcher.Filter = "(objectSid=" + mySID.Value + ")";
                sidSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

                SearchResult sidResult = sidSearcher.FindOne();

                if (sidResult != null)
                {
                    string resourceName = (sidResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]).ToString();
                    resourceName = resourceName.Substring(3, resourceName.Length - 3);
                    int stopAt = resourceName.IndexOf("OU=");
                    if (stopAt <= 0) stopAt = resourceName.IndexOf("CN=");
                    if (stopAt <= 0) stopAt = resourceName.IndexOf("DC=");

                    string resourceFound = resourceName.Substring(0, stopAt - 1);

                    if (resourceFound.ToUpper().Trim() == resourceGroupName.ToUpper().Trim())
                    {
                        // I only want to return a true if it is of a "Domain Local" type.
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static string GetCurrentDomainLDAP()
    {
        Domain domain = Domain.GetComputerDomain();

        return "LDAP://DC=" + domain.Name.Split('.')[0] + ",DC=" + domain.Name.Split('.')[1]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use System.DirectoryServices then from there get the group by its group name

like such

```
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext, "YourGroupName");
```

then you will know like this

```
group.IsSecurityGroup
```

There are only 2 types **Security** and **Distribution** so if it yeilds false then it is a distribution group

Now for Group Scope you have to do this

```
group.GroupScope
```

which returns a GroupScope.  Values are **Global**, **Universal** or **Local**

Comment: The Domain Group and the Global Group are both security groups.  I want to find out if the group is either of those.

Comment: Ahh Ok what you are asking is group scope.  I updated the answer above.